# property_service connect fail when useing __system_property_set for "socksProxySet" in c++ android

Tags: android, c++, properties, permissions, http-proxy

When I use "__system_property_set" setting the network proxy for the arm64-v8a Android system like this:

```cpp
__system_property_set ("socksProxySet", "true");
```

the program prompted me for a connection error. It's the function "send_prop_msg" reported it. I looked into the code ,and found it tried using "/dev/socket" to connect to property_service, and then failed:

```
    **E [PropSet]: connect fail**
    **E [PropSet]: send_prop_msg return err -1**
```

I changed to x86_ 64 Android Studio simulator testing, prompted:

```
    **W libc    : Unable to set property "socksProxySet" to "true": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)**
    **W TLThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:34): avc:  denied  { write } for  name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=357 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_30:s0:c182,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0 app=org.qtproject.example**
```

It seems like a permission issue, I don't know how to set the permissions. I created the app by QT. Please help me, masters, I've been tossing and turning for a long time. Thank you very much!